# ModuleScript is getting required and working, but the functions don't work (Roblox)

Tags: lua, roblox

So basically, I am making a game with a Press E to pick up weapon/item and I have 2 scripts that handle all of the work that needs to be done. However, whenever I try running a function inside of the ModuleScript from a ServerScript, it just plain out doesn't work.

I have already tried putting a print function inside of the function in the ModuleScript, but it seems to not even print to console. I also checked over both scripts to see any issues that might be leading to this issue, I couldn't find any.

Both scripts are not finished completely but done enough to give you a general idea.

ServerScript (the main script):

```lua
print("[GameName]: ToolHandler is initializing, please wait...")
--Getting required services within the game for later use. This still works even if the names aren't original.
local Workspace = game:GetService("Workspace")
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local ServerStorage = game:GetService("ServerStorage")
local SoundService = game:GetService("SoundService")
local UserInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")

--Getting required instances needed for the script to work.
local Tools = Workspace:WaitForChild("Tools")
local GameContent = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("GameContent")
local GameModules = GameContent:WaitForChild("GameModules")
local GameEvents = GameContent:WaitForChild("GameEvents")
local DestroyTouchModuleScript = GameModules:WaitForChild("DestroyTouchModule")
local GetItemEvent = GameEvents:WaitForChild("GetItem")

--Getting children of any instance if needed.
local AllTools = Tools:GetChildren()

--Requiring Module Scripts if any.
local DestroyTouchModule = require(DestroyTouchModuleScript)

--ChildAdded functions
Tools.ChildAdded:connect(function(Child)
    if Child:IsA("Tool") then
        DestroyTouch({Child})
    end
end)

Workspace.ChildAdded:connect(function(Child)
    if Child:IsA("Tool") then
        Child.Parent = Tools
    end
end)

--Functions that are required for the script to run efficently.
function DestroyTouch(List)
    for I = 1, #List do
        local Handle = List[I]:WaitForChild("Handle")
        local Tool = Handle.Parent
        if Handle ~= nil then
            local TouchInterest = Handle:WaitForChild("TouchInterest")
            if not TouchInterest then
                DestroyTouchModule.DestroyTouch(Tool)
            end
        end
    end
end

-- Initializing done
DestroyTouch(AllTools)

print("[GameName]: ToolHandler has initialized successfully.")
```

ModuleScript (prevents the user from picking the weapon/item up by touching it.):

```lua
local DestroyTouchModule = {}

print("DestroyModule: Initializing, please wait...")
function DestroyTouchModule.DestroyTouch(ToolRequired)
    print("a") --This is when I tried to see if it was a actual problem with the function or the code.
    local Handle = ToolRequired:WaitForChild("Handle")
    local TouchInterest = Handle:WaitForChild("TouchInterest")
    if Handle and TouchInterest then
        TouchInterest:Destroy()
        print("Tool: Successfully removed TouchInterest from Handle.")
    else
        warn("Tool: Handle or TouchInterest is missing, no work is required.")
    end

    Handle.ChildAdded:connect(function(Child)
        if Child:IsA("TouchTransmitter") then
            Child:Destroy()
        end
    end)
end

print("DestroyModule: Initialized with no issue.")

return DestroyTouchModule
```

What was to be expected was when the function ran, I should see "a" in the console, but I don't. In fact, I don't see anything printed in the log that is inside the function.

All I see in the output panel is:
[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSBWU.jpg)

Notice how there isn't any "a" inside of the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heyo,  assuming that `Child:IsA("Tool")` works properly, this should be a simple change to fix your problem. `DestroyTouch` is a function of DestroyTouchModule, you just need to call it properly :

```
Tools.ChildAdded:connect(function(Child)
    if Child:IsA("Tool") then
        -- Use the DestroyTouchModule to add event listeners to the Child.
        DestroyTouchModule.DestroyTouch(Child)
    end
end)
```

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem, really appreciate it :)